# Laravel 4 - Composer Error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I have some problems with composer and Laravel 4.
First I downloaded the laravel-master zip file.

But after starting the install command of Composer I get this error:

[Screenshot](http://www4.picfront.org/token/UNtX/2013/06/05/2141271.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The link to your screenshot is broken...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the OpenSSL extension for your PHP installation. In your `php.ini` file (in `C:\xampp\php`) **uncomment** the following line:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Just remove the `;` in front of it.

Once you've saved your changes, restart Apache, and it should work.

Comment: I am Using xampp, Composer giving the same open ssl missing error even after removing the ';' of openssl extension in php.ini.