# Laravel 4 /Composer Install Error

Tags: php, git, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I was following a noobies guide to Laravel, but sadly I am stumped on step one..

I have tried many threads relating to the same thing, but none seem to work - and I am stumped.
I have followed to the letter, this helpful video, and never diverted in any detail.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNn_tS2KpcY
```

For example I have changed all the required extension=php_openssl.dll's mentioned in posts such as this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940582/laravel-4-composer-error/16940691#16940691
```

As you might expect I am very new to coding, so I have provided images to help illustrate things I am not too sure about.

Firstly I download and install the .phar file, and my folder structure and files look like:

[image]

This is setup globally I assume? I also have the PATH variables added correctly when the installation prompts to add them.

So next I run composer in my command line, and successfully receive:
[image]

This to me, indicates Composer is installed at least?

Ok, next I make a folder in my WAMP server, and copy the contents from "Laravel-Master", which is from Laravels GIT and quick start guide: 
[image]

Next I cd to the www folder and run the command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist
```

Things seem to go fine, and it does make a new Laravel "project-name" (if the folder is empty)
but then errors:
[image]

```
Composer could not find the config file: c: programdata\composer setup\bin To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file.
```

This is most annoying as I stick very close to the video linked above, but do not get the same results.

Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: You aren't supposed to both download the contents of the Laravel repository manually **and** run `composer create-project`. If you do the former, your next command should be `composer install`, which will download Laravel's *dependencies*, not the app itself (which you already got manually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Composer installation is misconfigured (or rather un-configured.) I don't know what that video says about installing Composer however I would download an installation executable [here for Windows](https://github.com/composer/windows-setup/releases) and follow the instructions.

If you have done this, great! However something got screwed up in the installation process, so you should try running the same installer again.

According to [this](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3514) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25986667/1188035), you could also try this command instead:

```
COMPOSER=composer.json composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist
```

Comment: You absolute star, the line of code you supplied worked a charm!
I have no idea why the code from the tutorials didnt work, but thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better suited with Laravel Homestead, which already comes with everything you need to run Laravel in a Vagrant Box

```
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead
```